# Console.log of function state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function, I want console.log the output to show the state of isOpen, the expected output must be 'true' only.

```
open = () => {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: true
    })
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `setState()` is async, you need to call a callback, which executes after the state gets updates.

```
open = () => {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: true
     }, () => console.log(this.state.isOpen))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setState will take a callback function.

```
open = () => {
this.setState({
    isOpen: true
 }, () => {
   console.log(this.state.isOpen ? this.state.isOpen : '')
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `setState()` is async, you need to put `console.log` in callback of `setState`.

```
    open = () => {
    this.setState({
        isOpen: true
     }, ()=> {
      console.log(this.state.isOpen);
    }
```